# not Syncing CRM lookup field From Sitecore to CRM by batch pipeline

Tags: dynamics-crm-module

we are syncing the items from sitecore to dynamic 365 by batch pipelines.dynamic 365 Simple type is synced successfully. but in 
dynamic look up field is not updating.

1. CRM field (case field (look up field))
   Sitecore field (case field (single line text)).

Answer (score 0):

Simple type works because in this we do not need to create any reader, but in case of dropdown and look up field we need to create reader. You can read more information here https://www.codinglittlethings.com/2019/06/sitecore-9-dynamic-crm-connector-sync.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks Swati, Can you please  tell me about the look up field. how can we create the code defintions for look up field. There is an seperate entity in crm and also use can add new row in this entity.

Comment: @sandeep, I do not have lookup field code,  but as per my understanding it should have " code defination set" just like dropdown (mentioned in step 3)